# Entity Framework - Foreign key constraints not added for inherited entity

Tags: entity-framework, self-tracking-entities

It appears to me that a strange phenomenon is occurring with inherited entities (TPT) in EF4.

I have three entities.
1. Asset
2. Property
3. Activity

Property is a derived-type of Asset.
Property has many activities (many-to-many)

When modeling this in my EDMX, everything seems fine until I try to insert a new Property into the database. If the property does not contain any Activity, it works, but all hell breaks loose when I add some new activities to the new Property.

As it turns out after 2 days of crawling the web and fiddling around, I noticed that in the EF store (SSDL) some of the constraints between entities were not picked up during the update process.

> Property_Activity table which links properties and activities show only
>   one constraint
>   FK_Property_Activity_Activity but
>   FK_Property_Activity_Property was
>   missing.

I knew this is an Entity Framework anomoly because when I switched the relationship in the database to:

Asset <--> Asset_Activity <--> Activity

After an update, all foreign key constraints are picked up and the save is successful, with or without activities in the new property.

1. Is this intended or a bug in EF?
2. How do I get around this problem?
3. Should I abandon inheritance altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Not a but but a poor visual designer.
2. Its generally best to simply manage the Entity XML by hand.
3. No inheritance works well for many situations.

Basically I use the update from database in the visual designer but knowing that the designer has its quirks.  I have simply used the update from database to stub out the basics of what I want.  Then I go into the Entity XML my self and clean it up the way I want.  Just of note Complex types are a pain with the designer.  If you plan to use complex types get ready to learn your Entity XML well.

Comment: I sometimes just delete the edmx file and recreate it.

Comment: yeah i have had to do that before too after the designer added more crap than i needed.  It was easier to go back to the beginning than to try to make rhyme or reason out of what the designer added and omitted.

Comment: Is this something that the MS team is going to improve on if any cares to speculate? A good example is Designer in RC adding StoreGenerated ="Identity" to linking entities.

Comment: I imagine they will work on the designer some more but the truth is, the power is in the framework itself and the framework is very well designed.